# Cross Compiling On Windows?

Tags: c, windows, unix, gcc, cross-compiling

I have the GNU GCC compiler for Windows.  I read that it is able to function as a cross compiler.

How do I do this?  What command option(s) will produce an shared library that can be used by MacOS/Linux platforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **build** your own cross-compiler, i.e. you need to get the GCC *sources* and compile them with a desired target-architecture. Then you have to cross-compile all the libraries.

The process is fairly involved and lengthy. The usual GNU makefiles are pretty good at supporting this (through HOST, BUILD and ARCH variables), but if possible you should leave this to a higher-level abstraction. `crosstool` is one such tool that comes to mind, but I don't know if it's available for Windows.

It's possible that you'll be able to find pre-build Windows binaries of GCC on the internet that target a particular architecture.

Comment: Is it even worth it?  I would need to the platform's API for the native code right?  In the case of mac at least, there is no way for me to get an SDK.

Comment: What API? MacOSX supports Posix, so you can write a huge amount of code that will compile on it... it all depends on what you want.

Comment: but doesn't Mac have specific system functions/header files?

Comment: You can get a Windows to Linux compiler here: https://sourcery.mentor.com/sgpp/lite/ia32/portal/subscription10027lite=IA32 but I think you're on your own for Mac.

Comment: Are there any step by step tutorials on building a cross compiler?